# Tool to search for packages whose installed version does not match any version from a repository?

Tags: package-management, ppa, versions

I just upgraded from Lucid to Maverick, and as expected, all my PPAs were disabled. I have re-enabled most of the ones that I want, but I would like to get a list of all packages that I installed from PPAs that I no longer have enabled. I feel that the best way to do this would be to search for all packages where the currently installed version of that package does not match any version from a currently-enabled repository. Is there an easy way to search for such packages.

Command-line solutions welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `aptitude search ~o` or longer version `aptitude search ?obsolete`. From documentation, it "*match installed packages that cannot be downloaded*".

Comment: This will also show things you download manually as .deb files, things that you build and package yourself and things that are no longer in a repository... But it should give you a rough idea.

Comment: Cool. I realize that manually-downloaded debs and suchlike will also appear, but if I manually installed it, I can manually sift through it, so that's not a problem.